# In Excel, by Sorting the blank character should come first

Tags: excel, sorting

I try to sort the data in Excel 2010 The blank character always comes at the end of the result. I sorted A-Z order an in Z-A Order. No effect by blank rows..?

Any idea how i can do that?

Comment: Where do you want the blank rows? At the beginning rather than the end?

Comment: @Raystafarian Yes, At the beginning

Comment: There's no way to do that without a _helper column_ that would have values in it. In the column next to all of this put the formula `=A1=""` this will return a `false` for non-blanks and a `true` for blanks. Then do custom sort, first by the true/false then ascending for the other value

Comment: I did also in the same way. But it is alittle burdensome. Don't you think?

Comment: Absolutely it is, but it's the only way that I know of.

Comment: @Raystafarian Write your comment as an answer that i can select as an accepted answer

Comment: Just for clarity this issue is in Excel 2013 as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no way to do that without a helper column that would have values in it. In the column next to all of this put the formula `=A1=""` this will return a `false` for non-blanks and a `true` for blanks. Then do custom sort, first by the true/false then ascending for the other value

Comment: Note that the sort order of the helper column has to be changed from the default of "Smallest to Largest" to "Largest to Smallest".

Answer (score 7):

It's a pain, but you can highlight your data, then press F5, select special, then select blanks. You can then color them or fill them with the single space others have suggested by hitting F2, then typing your space, and holding CTRL when you press enter.

I recommend color though, as you don't actually have to modify your data in a way that won't matter if you aren't otherwise using color to identify your data.

Answer (score 3):

Replace all nulls with a single space using find and replace. Space will sort correctly.

Comment: How do you find a null?  Excel won't search for a blank item.  A way to do this would be to copy a cell with just a space, find and select, go to special, choose blanks and paste.

Answer (score 3):

If you populate your blank cells in the column you are sorting by with ="", you can then sort by column choosing custom list in the order selection.  In custom list, set the sort value to ="".  This will sort with the blank columns on top and the columns with values below.  ="" displays as a blank cell so no visible change will be made to your data.  Obviously adding a value to the cell would remove the formula and it would then sort as a non blank.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional formatting, highlight blank rows a certain color and then sort on cell color instead of cell value. You can do this by choosing a new formatting rule, find the choice "format only cells that contain"..., there should be a drop down selection somewhere for "Blanks" and then choose a cell color for the rule.  Then when sorting, change the default from sort from cell values to sort on cell color (this is a drop down choice)

Comment: This was the best solution for me, especially since I'm using a checklist where status changes frequently. No need for a helper column, and no need to maintain special formatting or remember to add spaces or whatever.

From Conditional Formatting choose Highlight Cells Rules, Equal To..., and enter "" (two quotes, no space), and pick a highlight color. Then use Sort by Color in the column filter popup or Cell Color from the Sort On option in the sort dialog.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is format your lines as dark shade of blue,light shade, dark shade. (once you done first two use the format painter to copy down)

then hightlight your first line, go to conditional formatting. =$a1="" then change format to white background white font. (a1 will be first cell of the line , make sure the $ is only on the letter not $a$1.

ok then apply to box =a1:m200 ( what ever your table are)

fineally go to sort a to z custom. sort first by colour , select white and next box select last.

2nd sort by a to z !

ta DA :D all pretty and auto formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but what I did was (with my cursor in the blank field), I hit my SPACE bar once. I did this for all the fields that were blank. Then when I sorted from A to Z, it worked with all the blanks displaying first.